# A truce between the ground and sky

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for this short story of the ground and sky arguing and then reaching a truce.  It features a star who acts as arbiter.  I wanted to know if anyone else has found or read it?

Comment: Are there any extra details you remember that you could [edit] in? [This checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) offers some pointers if you need some assistance. Do you remember why the ground and sky were arguing? Did they all have names, or were they called simply "Ground" and "Sky"? Was this an English story, or in another language? Where did you encounter this story? In an anthology collection? Mythology? Online?